# Does return value account for space complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, space-complexity

Below is an algorithm which is used to generate multiple sets. Precisely it solves the following question `Print all combination of element in the array such that first element of array is d and
next element in the array can be +1 or -1 the previous element in the array. Code was required.
Input: num=4, level=3. Output - 4, 3, 2 || 4, 3, 4 || 4, 5, 4 || 4, 5, 6`.

This question does not uses `int[] arr = new int[level]` as a data store which eventually gets copied into a list of int arrays.

What is the space complexity of the following code ? Is it O(level) ie the storage used to solve the problem or is it O(2^level - 1) ie the size of the return type ?

```
public static List<int[]> getCombinations(int num, int level) {
        final List<int[]> combinations = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int[] arr = new int[level]; 
        computeCombinations(num, level - 1, 0, combinations, arr);  // note : its level - 1, since currentlevel is set to 0.
        return combinations;
    }


    private static void computeCombinations(int num, int level, int currLevel, List<int[]> list, int[] arr) {
        arr[currLevel] = num;

        if (currLevel == level) {
            // list.add(arr);  <- wrong to do it so
            int[] temp = new int[arr.length];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, temp, 0, arr.length);
            list.add(temp);
            return;
        }

        computeCombinations(num - 1, level, currLevel + 1, list, arr);
        computeCombinations(num + 1, level, currLevel + 1, list, arr);
    }
```

Comment: I would say `O(level * 2^(level-1))`, since the code apparently generates the entire list in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space complexity accounts for the amount of live memory used by the algorithm, therefore the `ArrayList<int[]>` factors in to the complexity.  However, the algorithm description given at the top of your post says that you only need to print the combinations, not return them; if you immediately print out your combinations after you create them and then discard them (i.e. destructively update the combination rather than making a copy of it) then you'll improve your space complexity.